# POST method in WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, post

I want to use POST methon from REST API tu update a user profile from a backend website to FrontEnd WordPress. The next code is suppose to update the name, description and the slug.

```
if (isset($_POST['update_frontend'])) {
            $url = $setting['front_end_host_wp'].'users/'.$item_id.'/';

            $data1 = array(
                        'description'   => $data['content'],
                        'name'          => $data['nume'],
                        'slug'          => $data['slug'],
                        'parent'        => 0,
                        'meta'          => array()
                        );

        $result = $df->runGuzzle('POST', $url, $data1);
            printpre($result);

        }
```

I want to update the user_status(Approved, Pending or Denied) and other info like, name, email etc. But the code above is not working.

Comment: check out the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#update-a-user. There is no `parent` attribute and the POST url should be like this `POST /wp/v2/users/<id>` with no trailing slash

Comment: Yeah but i need to update de user_status, Status field. And i don't know how.

Comment: check this out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/300793/62221

Comment: I've seen that post, but i'm using "WP User Frontend"